# What is verify token in Facebook Realtime API

Tags: python, facebook, real-time, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to implement Facebook Realtime api with my application. I want to pull the feeds from my 'facebook PAGE'.
I've obtained app_access_token...

```
app_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'       

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + FB_CLIENT_ID + '/subscriptions?access_token=' + app_access_token

url_params = {'access_token':app_access_token,'object':'page', 'fields':'feed', 'callback_url':'http://127.0.0.1:8000/fb_notifications/', 'verify_token' : 'I am taking a random string here...'}

urlResponse = call_url(url, url_params)
```

Everytime I call the url with url parameters, I get error : HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
But If I call the url without url parameters, I get `{"data": []}`

Please note that in url parameters, I'm taking verify_token, a random string and callback_url is not same as the redirect_url parameter for the facebook application.(just wanna know is it necessary to put the same url here?)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I'm using python/django to implement.

Comment: -1 : Neither the question itself nor the accepted answer have anything to do with the title of the question. Search results return this question which is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use POST rather than GET, with an empty body & `object`, `fields`, `callback_url` and `verify_token` passed as query parameters in the url.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/.

Comment: In my code call_url makes a POST call...
Code - 
urlresponse = urllib2.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode(url_params), timeout=socket.getdefaulttimeout()).read().... And I've tried after removing access_token from url_params... still not working.... :(

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Nope.... Still not working...
Can you please provide me some sample codes of adding subscription to Facebbok realtime api....
Thanks... :)

Comment: I've implemented this in Java with a POST to `https://graph.facebook.com/${APP_ID}/subscriptions?access_token=XXX&object=user&fields=feed&verify_token=YYY&callback_url=http://example.com` with an empty body.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured this out...
.
.
.
.
Make a POST request to url :

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/' + FB_CLIENT_ID + '/subscriptions?access_token=' + app_access_token + '&object=page&fields=name&callback_url=' + YOUR_CALLBACK_URL + '&verify_token=' + ANY_RANDOM_STRING + '&method=post'
```

Pass {} as post parameters.....
Make sure that your_callback_url should be reachable. It will not work on localhost(I guess so... I was not able test it on localhost.)

So in Python the code should be :

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + FB_CLIENT_ID + '/subscriptions?access_token=' + app_access_token + '&object=page&fields=name&callback_url=' + YOUR_CALLBACK_URL + '&verify_token=' + ANY_RANDOM_STRING + '&method=post'

url_params = {}

urlResponse = urllib2.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode(url_params), timeout=socket.getdefaulttimeout()).read()
```

urlResponse should be null.

Function attached with callback_url should return:

```
def callback_function(request):
   if request.GET: #(Handle this properly!!!)
       return request.GET.get('hub.challenge') #hub_challenge for PHP Developers. :)
```

Please let me know in case of any doubts!!!

To know how to handle notifications from the FB:
Kindly visit the following URL:
[Handling notifications request from Facebook after successful subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495461/handling-notifications-request-from-facebook-after-successful-subscription)

Comment: Please accept my answer above (rather than your own) - even though it wasn't Python it gave you the solution.

Comment: Yes ofcourse.. .solution was given by you... Thanks a lot once again... :)